# extraPortMappings for kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kind

I am be able map my NodePort service to localhost using a configuration file like this:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 32000
    hostPort: 3000
    protocol: tcp
- role: worker
- role: worker
```

What is the equivalent of `extraPortMappings` when i use kubeadm to create my clusters?